# how to make a template function like R f<void(int)>(args...)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, c++17

now i want to create a function looked like `f<void(int)>(args...)`,my code is:

```
template<typename T>
struct A{};

template<typename F>
A<F> f4();

template<typename R,typename... Args>
A<R(Args...)> f4<R(Args...)>() {
    return A<R(Args...)>();
}
```

but it does not work and
vs gives error C2768

how can i do that?

Comment: It would help if you could try to be a bit more specific on what it is you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't partial specialize function template; class template can. e.g.

```
// primary template
template<typename F>
struct f4_s {
    static A<F> f4() {
        return A<F>();
    }
};

// partial specialization
template<typename R,typename... Args>
struct f4_s<R(Args...)> {
    static A<R(Args...)> f4() {
        return A<R(Args...)>();
    }
};

template<typename T>
auto f4() {
    return f4_s<T>::f4();
}
```

then

```
f4<int>();           // call the primary version
f4<int(int,char)>(); // call the specialization version
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JfAUlgIOjsg46G16)

Or apply overloading with function templates. e.g.

```
template<typename F>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_function_v<F>, A<F>> f4() {
    return A<F>();
}    

template<typename F>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_function_v<F>, A<F>> f4() {
    return A<F>();
}
```

then

```
f4<int>();           // call the 1st overload
f4<int(int,char)>(); // call the 2nd overload
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jMJsk2ufqBsNpHIk)